# Does the sqlite 'file change counter' overflow when it exceeds the maximum size?

Tags: sqlite

According to http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html SQLite3 maintains a 4-byte big-endian integer `file change counter` in byte `24..27` of the database file.

Does the `file change counter` overflow when it exceeds the maximum size?

(I feel the answer is: **yes, it does overflow**)

---

I ask because I wanted something akin to checksum for the sqlite file, and found `file change counter` through another StackOverflow question: 
[Checksum for a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637764/checksum-for-a-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual value of the file change counter does not have any meaning (it is *not* a version number); the only important thing is that it is different from all other recent values.

A quick test shows that the value wraps around:

```sh
$ sqlite3 test.db 'create table t(x);'
$ od --skip-bytes 24 --read-bytes 4 -tx1 test.db | cut -c9-
00 00 00 01
(lots of changes ...)
$ od --skip-bytes 24 --read-bytes 4 -tx1 test.db | cut -c9-
ff ff ff ff
$ sqlite3 test.db 'drop table t;'
$ od --skip-bytes 24 --read-bytes 4 -tx1 test.db | cut -c9-
00 00 00 00
```

Comment: Thanks! I just now realized I can verify this behavior by using a hex editor (e.g. vim).